# Procmail - auto reply with attachment

Tags: email, procmail

I am trying to auto-reply using procmail. I want to send back an HTML form with attachments (images; jpg/png). Is there a simple way to accomplish this? This is my piece of code so far:

```
:0
| ($FORMAIL -rA "$XLOOP" -i "Content-Type: text/html; Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" -A "Reply-To: noreply@myserver.com" -I "From: noreply@myserver.com"; cat $HOME/reply.html) | $SENDMAIL -oi -t
```

The `reply.html` is correctly passed & sent to the sender, however I can not see the images that are defined in the html file. I have tried the base64 image encoding without success as Google seems to skip them and displays ugly squares.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have should work, provided the file `$HOME/reply.html` is correctly formatted.  Alas, as per your description, it isn't.

Incidentally, I would factor out as much as possible of the static headers into this file, and only use `formail` to prepend headers which cannot be calculated in advance.  That leaves you with just

```
:0
| (formail -rA "$XLOOP" | grep .; cat $HOME/reply.html) | $SENDMAIL -oi -t
```

in the Procmail recipe (and if the `XLOOP` header is in fact also static, you could factor that into the template as well.  The `grep .` is because `formail` supplies an empty line as the "neck" between the headers and body when it generates reply headers, but we don't want that here, as we will be supplying additional headers in the file we are catenating after `formail`'s headers; so we remove the empty line from the output).

The trick is to have the different MIME parts hook into each other correctly.  Here is a template of sorts.  Note that this isn't an HTML file at all -- it is a MIME structure which contains an HTML part, an image part, and some other chaff -- so you might want to rename it.

```
From: noreply@myserver.com
X-Reply-To: The reply-to: header is redundant if its value is the same as From:
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="reasonablyuniquegobbledygook"

--reasonablyuniquegobbledygook
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

This message is HTML-only because I hate you.  Nothing personal, I hate
everyone.

--reasonablyuniquegobbledygook
Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<html><head><title>Reply</title></head><body><p>
I cannot think of a situation where you would genuinely want to base64
your HTML.
<img src=3D"cid:logo.png"></p></body></html>

--reasonablyuniquegobbledygook
Content-Type: image/png; name="logo.png"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Id: <logo.png>

SGVyZSBpcyBzb21lIGJhc2U2NCBmb3IgeW91LiAgVGhpcyBpcyBvYnZpb3VzbHkgYWN0dWFsbHkg
dGV4dCwgbm90IGltYWdlL3BuZyBkYXRhLgo=

--reasonablyuniquegobbledygook--
```

Notice how the top-level MIME part is `multipart/related` and then contains individual MIME parts which can link to each other.  (This is all typed up ad hoc so apologies for any mistakes or oversights.)

Comment: Revisiting now, I am disappointed that I didn't put anything more interesting in the `base64` data.

Comment: Works really well, thank you!

Comment: Is there any reason not to use `Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit` and include all those files in raw? Are there really any environments in real world that do not already have 8 bits fully working?

Comment: Note that the separator is actually linefeed (CRLF) followed by two dashes and the boundary string. So if you end a part with a single linefeed followed by the dashes, the  data is interpreted to end without a linefeed. in the above example, the HTML part ends with a single line feed. You don't need extra linefeed for base64 encoding so there's no need for the extra empty line before the final boundary mark.

Comment: Just `8bit` still doesn't allow arbitrary contents, and `binary` which does runs up against line-length restrictions in SMTP which are still very real. So I'd recommend encoding your payloads anyway, and then making them 7-bit US-ASCII too is a very minor additional requirement, and guaranteed to work absolutely everywhere.

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen I'm not sure what you are trying to say in the comment about boundary strings. Typically Unix tools allow or even require LF line endings in local input streams and files, and translate to the required wire format with CRLF line endings on the fly during message submission. If you have a tool or programming library which explicitly requires CRLF line endings before boundary strings, I would be tempted to submit a bug report if it's not explicitly documented.

Comment: Yes, I mean that the wire format for the separator is CR+LF+"--"+the boundary string. How some specific API works while sending the message depends on the API. The example above, especially the one with base64 encoding, might make one believe that the wire format for the boundary is CR+LF+CR+LF+"--"+the boundary string because of the extra line at the end of the base64 encoding.

Comment: @tripleee You're right! The RFC 5322 section 2.1.1 still requires  that any single line `MUST` not exceed 998 "characters" (I assume bytes because a character could be up to 4 bytes long in UTF-8 or UTF32 encoding.) I misremembered that it would have been SHOULD and was questioning if this still needed nowadays. https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5322#section-2.1.1 –– that also means that HTML should also use base64 encoding in email unless you can quarantee that it doesn't contain too long lines.

Comment: You can safely use quoted-printable wherever you can use base64; which to use depends on asthetics and/or simplicity of your code. Because HTML will tend to be dominated by tags which are ASCII, I would generally prefer the more human-readable  QP even when the actual text needs to be =hex-encoded entirely (i.e. most non-Western scripts).